# SWI-Prolog: How to write a solution to the command line output?

Tags: command-line-interface, swi-prolog, clpr

I am using SWI-Prolog with the [clpr](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpqr.html) library for solving constraints over real numbers. I do this by calling SWI-Prolog from the [command line](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=cmdline) and parsing the output by another program.

For example, to solve something like `{F = 1.8 * C + 32}, {C = 25}.` I generate the following command:

```
swipl \
  -g "use_module(library(clpr))" \
  -g "{F = 1.8 * C + 32}, {C = 25}, write(\"F -> \"), write(F), write(\"\\n\")" \
  -g halt
```

And the output from SWI-Prolog is:

```
F -> 77.0
```

This works great if the result is a plain number but not if the result is again a constraint (or a more complex solution in general). For example, for `{X > 3}, {Y < 5}, {X + Y = 10}.` I get the solution `{Y < 5.0, X = 10.0 - Y}` in the SWI-Prolog environment but I did not found a way to write this to the command line output. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Sure you do not want to use [tag:clpq] in stead? clpr is riddled with numerical problems everywhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dump/3 predicate, for example:

```
{X > 3}, {Y < 5}, {X + Y = 10}, dump([X,Y], [x,y], L), write(L).
```

produces:

```
 [y=10.0-x,x>5.0]
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for.